# Get Internal Storage path for pulling over ADB

Tags: adb, internal-storage

To clarify, by `internal storage` I'm referring to the folder that's shown to you on a PC when you connect your device.

I can use `adb shell pm list -f` `-s`/`-3` to get the paths of system apps and user apps respectively. I don't know how I can find the internal storage path though.

From my 5 minutes of googling I've found it could be at `/sdcard/sdcard0`, though I've yet to see that in any official documentation and I have no clue if that's consistent across phones/android versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your Android version, there could be a few "canonical" directories:

- In old times `sdcard` and `userdata` are two separate partitions:

  ```
  /storage/sdcard0
  ```
- In modern times (mostly Android 5+), `sdcard` is part of `userdata`

  ```
  /storage/emulated/0
  /storage/emulated/legacy
  ```
- Finally, there's *always* a convenient way to reach it

  ```
  /sdcard
  ```

  Simple, right?

Comment: I would assume `/sdcard` is considered a partition. Are there any caveats for copying files into this dir/partition in an `updater-script` ?

Comment: @MattM. Nope. For sure.